# ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 6: Unknown column 'SCORE' in 'having clause

Tags: sql

My sql query gives `ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 6: Unknown column 'SCORE' in 'having clause'`

Please help to resolve this issue.

**QUERY:**

```
select ID, NAME
from STUDENT 
having SCORE > AVG(SCORE)
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? What are you trying to do? Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `HAVING` clause without also using `GROUP BY`, unless you're on MySQL.  Instead, if your logic is to find every student record whose average score be larger than the overall average, then use a subquery to find that average:

```sql
SELECT ID, NAME
FROM STUDENT 
WHERE SCORE > (SELECT AVG(SCORE) FROM STUDENT)
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: SQL Server also allows it, but assumes `GROUP BY ()`. A windowed `AVG` would be more efficient usually.

Comment: Technically you can have a HAVING clause with no GROUP BY, but I can't figure out when it should make any sense.

Comment: @jarlh In fact, MySQL allows this, and it is valid syntax.  Not sure what the OP's database is though.

Comment: I meant even ANSI SQL allows HAVING without GROUP BY. _Let HC be the <having clause>. Let TE be the <table expression> that immediately contains HC. If TE
does not immediately contain a <group by clause>, then “GROUP BY ()” is implicit._

Comment: @jarlh I sort of figured you were citing this.  Good to know that MySQL actually sticks to the standard from time to time.